# create a table in html that dynamically adjusts the number of items in each row depending on the size of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is structured as following:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...
      </td>
      ...
      <td>...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to add a css class to it that makes the td elements break into a new line as soon as the end of the screen is reached. currently a scrollbar is created within the table.

Is there a way to do it without requiring to break out of the tr element?

Comment: And how have you attempted to solve this? Please include any code that you have tried thus far.

Comment: You can't because this is the definition of `display: table`. If you want line breaks in the rows you should work with flexbox...

Comment: Or display grid...